# Reference or counter-example for Closed Graph Theorem for multivalued maps in general topological spaces

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, counterexamples

Could someone be so kind to point me in the direction of a citeable proof of the following version of the Closed Graph Theorem? (i.e. assuming this is true, could someone give me a literature reference, or if it is false, a counter-example.))

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are topological spaces. For the correspondence $f : A \to B$ with closed values (i.e. $f(a)$ - closed for all $a \in A$ and $f(a)\neq\emptyset$), closed domain and compact range, to be upper hemicontinuous it is sufficient and necessary for $f$ to have closed graph.

Edited to add: $B$ is *not* assumed Hausdorff.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify in your post whether you assume some separation axioms (in particular whether compact means compact Hausdorff). And also whether closed domain means that $\{a\in A; f(a)\ne\emptyset\}$ is closed. (Some authors only value non-empt valued multifunctions.)

Comment: And maybe you could edit the title to become more descriptive. (There are several results called *closed graph theorem* or related to closed graphs. It would be probably an improvement if the title indicated that this is about correspondences/multifunctions.)

Comment: Some background to the question: I haven't done any mathematics since last century. Trying to work up a manuscript from 1998 in which I implicitly used the above "theorem" without mentioning any separability conditions. I haven't noted a source in my draft. Only equivalent I have found is the statement from hemicontinuity page on Wikipedia. As I didn't use multivalued maps regularly, I assume I must have plucked this result from some standard source. Possible I looked at a source that distinguished between quasi-compact and compact a la Bourbaki without me recognizing the distinction was made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this result is mentioned in [Wikipedia article on hemicontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicontinuity#Closed_Graph_Theorem), the [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicontinuity#References) mentioned there might be a reasonable place to look for this result.

If you simply try searching for ["upper hemicontinuous" "closed graph"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22upper+hemicontinuous%22+%22closed+graph%22&tbm=bks) in Google Books, there are several reasonably looking results. (Of course, you can also try [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22upper+hemicontinuous%22+%22closed+graph%22) and [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22upper+hemicontinuous%22+%22closed+graph%22).) Notice that some authors use the name *upper semicontinuous instead of upper hemicontinuous. This gives us some other reasonable search phrases - again you can try [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22upper+semicontinuous%22+%22closed+graph%22&tbm=bks), [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22upper+semicontinuous%22+%22closed+graph%22) or [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22upper+semicontinuous%22+%22closed+graph%22).

---

Aliprantis C.D., Border K.C. *Infinite-dimensional analysis* (3ed., Springer, 2005), [page 561](https://books.google.com/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA561):

> **17.9 Definition** A correspondence $\varphi \colon X \twoheadrightarrow Y$ between topological spaces is
>   **closed**, or **has closed graph**, if its graph 
>   $$\operatorname{Gr}\varphi = \{(x,y)\in X\times Y; y\in\varphi(x)\}$$
>   is a closed subset of $X\times Y$.
>
> **17.11 Closed Graph Theorem** A correspondence with compact Hausdorff range space is closed if and only if it is upper hemicontinuous and closed-valued.

---

If $\varphi$ is single-valued (i.e., $|\varphi(x)|=1$ for each $x$), then the definition of upper hemicontinuity becomes continuity and the above result says that a function with compact Hausdorff codomain is continuous if and only if it has closed graph. (This is also sometimes called [closed graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem).) As can be seen from counterexamples given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108709/is-the-graph-g-f-x-fx-in-x-times-y-x-in-x-a-closed-subset-of-x/108721#108721), the assumption that $Y$ is Hausdorff cannot be omitted in the closed graph theorem for functions. (There is an example of a function to a compact space, which is continuous and does not have closed graph.) Of course, this means that it cannot be omitted from the close graph theorem for upper hemicontinuous multifunctions, either.

---

**EDIT:** Since I made this post, the Wikipedia article linked above was edited and now ([link to the current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hemicontinuity&oldid=730453869)) it contains the following reference for the theorem in question:
J.-P. Aubin, H. Frankowska: *Set-Valued Analysis* (Birkhäuser, 1990), [page 42](https://books.google.com/books?id=cVUl3smcGlcC&pg=PA42)

> **Proposition 1.4.8.** The graph of an upper semicontinuous set-valued map $F\colon X\to Y$ with closed domain and closed values is closed.
>
> The converse is true if we assume that $Y$ is compact.

Here domain is the set $\operatorname{Dom}(F)=\{x\in X; F(x)\ne\emptyset\}$ (defined on [page 34](https://books.google.com/books?id=cVUl3smcGlcC&pg=PA34)).

Comment: Have obviously searched Google etc. and all the texts I have available. The wording of this theorem is similar to the Wikipedia entry, thus I suspect it is the source, i.e. the Wikipedia "theorem" is unsupported by the reference. Munkres' (1975) "Topology ", states an almost identical Closed Graph theorem on p172 (only assuming single-valued maps and gives continuity) which also has the Hausdorff requirement. I used the Munkres theorem in a corollary, so this makes me think I deliberately left out Hausdorff in the original result. 

Thank you for your effort, but the question is still open.

Comment: @SteveSiller I updated my post. If I did not miss something, the result (or at least one implication) is no longer true if you omit $T_2$.

Comment: Thank you for adding the link to the counter-example. That seals it.

Comment: The Wikipedia article has been edited since your post. Now it contains [Proposition 1.4.8](https://books.google.com/books?id=cVUl3smcGlcC&pg=PA42) from Aubin, Frankowska: Set-Valued Analysis as a reference.